# How to reduce the cognitive complexity in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have a question regarding this piece of code:

```
doc = nlp(text)
words = nlp(text).ents[0]
for entity in doc.ents:
   self.entity_list = [entity]

left = [
{'Left': str(words[entity.start - 1])} if words[entity.start - 1] and not words[entity.start - 1].is_punct and not
words[entity.start - 1].is_space
else
{'Left': str(words[entity.start - 2])} if words[entity.start - 2] and not words[entity.start - 2].is_punct and not
words[entity.start - 2].is_space
else
{'Left': str(words[entity.start - 3])} for entity in nlp(text).ents]

entities = [{'Entity': str(entity)} for entity in doc.ents]

right = [
{'Right': str(words[entity.end])} if (entity.end < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[
    entity.end].is_punct and not words[entity.end].is_space
else
{'Right': str(words[entity.end + 1])} if (entity.end + 1 < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[
    entity.end + 1].is_punct and not words[entity.end + 1].is_space
else
{'Right': str(words[entity.end + 2])} if (entity.end + 2 < self.entity_list[-1].end) and not words[
    entity.end + 2].is_punct and not words[entity.end + 2].is_space
else
{'Right': 'null'}
for entity in nlp(text).ents]
```

I was asking for a solution a few days ago, regarding obtaining side words of an entity with SpaCy in Python3.

I found the solution and updated my question with the answer. However, it looks very complicated and ugly.

My question is:

**How can I reduce the cognitive complexity here in order to get more clean and readable code?**

Maybe with iterator? or something that Python3 has to control this kind of structures better?

If anyone has a solution or suggestion for that, I would appreciate.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code so we can help.

Comment: Done, sorry for the complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should both move the computation of indexes to dedicated functions and iterate instead of manually listing

```
def get_left_index(entity, words):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        if (
            words[entity.start - i]
            and not words[entity.start - i].is_punct
            and not words[entity.start - i].is_space
        ):
            return entity.start - i
    return entity.start - (i + 1)


def get_right_index(entity, entity_list, words):
    for i in range(3):
        if (
            (entity.end + i < entity_list[-1].end)
            and not words[entity.end + i].is_punct
            and not words[entity.end + i].is_space
        ):
            return entity.end + i


left = [
    {"Left": str(words[get_left_index(entity, words)])} for entity in nlp(text).ents
]

entities = [{"Entity": str(entity)} for entity in doc.ents]

right = [
    {"Right": str(words[get_right_index(entity, self.entity_list, words)])}
    if get_right_index(entity, self.entity_list, words) is not None
    else {"Right": "null"}
    for entity in nlp(text).ents
]
```

Comment: I didn't know the closure functions in python. That's cool. Thanks